# How to simplify an expression using a differential equation as an assumption?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector-calculus

I have a fluid dynamics flow described by a 3D velocity field such as

```
u = {ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], uz[x, y, z]}
```

I want to calculate `Curl[Curl[u, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"], {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"]`. The result of such calculation is an intricate expression involving crossed derivatives. I would like to further simplify the resulting expression using the fact that the fluid is incompressible, so that

```
Div[u, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"] == 0.
```

However, using `Simplify` with this last equation as an assumption does not work.

I was wondering how would one simplify an expression using a differential equation as an assumption, or if someone could help me understand what's the correct/best way to do this. Your help will be much appreciated.

PS: I know that in cartesian coordinates `Curl[Curl[u]] == - Laplacian[u]` for an incompressible fluid; what I'm trying to do is just come up with a general solution for any coordinate system. I'm just testing it on cartesian coordinates as a starting point.

Comment: I think you will need to "algebraicize", that is, treat derivatives as independent of variables and of one another. Then the simplifying equation is just a polynomial in these variables, and you can use `PolynomialReduce` to do rewriting of higher derivatives in terms of lower, for example.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your tips. Would you be so kind as to illustrate your comment with an example? I think I understand what you propose but I am not sure on how to implement it. Thanks again.

Comment: @m_goldberg: I've seen you reformatted my question, I just wanted to say thanks for that. If you don't mind my asking: How do you achieve that with the editor? I'm not asking for a full explanation, just a single reference would do.

Comment: There is help available right on the page where you enter your question. As soon a you put your mouse cursor into the text entry box, a help message appears to the right of entry box. At the bottom of the message there are three links giving further help. The first one will take you to a page giving details on the markdown formatting we use on this site. Another good way to learn is simply to click on the edit button at the bottom of any well-formatted question. This will show you the formatting commands that were used.

Answer (score 1):

Just an outline really, but too long for a comment.

The idea is along the following lines.

```
u = {ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], uz[x, y, z]};
cc = Curl[Curl[u, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"], {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"];
dv = Div[u, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"];
```

Take another round of derivatives to obtain more simplifying equations.

```
derivs2 = Map[D[dv, #] &, {x, y, z}];
allzeroderivs = Join[{dv}, derivs2];
```

One can now reduce the curl by these equations, as below. In this example it will not give any notable simplification.

```
PolynomialReduce[cc, allzeroderivs, vars][[All, 2]]
```

One can in some cases do more by ordering the "variables" in some way, forming a Groebner basis, and using that as the second argument to `PolynomialReduce` (making sure to keep the variable lists and term orders the same).